# Why if I use if else it works and if I use ternary operator it doesn't?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I'm new to C# and I come from C++.

Why if I use "if else" it works but if I use ternary operator it doesn't?

I thought that It was because of "Console.Writeline()" in the third part and I replaced with a common assignment but there's the same issue.

Thank you in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Board
    {
        private char[,] board = new char[3, 3];
        public void move (int g, int x, int y) //player, x , y position
        {
            char sign = ' ';

            switch (g)
            {
                case '1':
                    sign = '0';
                    break;
                case '2':
                    sign = 'x';
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Input Error");
                    break;
            }

          //error (x > 1 && x < 4 && y > 1 && y < 4) ? (board[x - 1, y - 1] = sign) : (Console.WriteLine("Error"));

            if (x > 1 && x < 4 && y > 1 && y < 4)
            {
                board[x - 1, y - 1] = sign;
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Error");

        }
    }

    class Game
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't"? Does it do something you don't expect? If so, what?

Comment: You have to say what "does not work" means. Do  you get an error message? If yes, what message? Is the behaviour different from what you expect? If yes, what is the expected and actual behaviour?

Comment: Umh you're right. It doesn't even compile. I use Visual Studio in italian. It says that it's not possible to infer the kind of conditional expression because it doesn't exist a "char" to "void" implicit conversion.

Comment: How were you trying to write your ternary operator? If you tried `board[x-1,y-1] =  (x > 1 && x < 4 && y > 1 && y < 4) ? sign : 'n'` it should have worked. If you just tried `(x > 1 && x < 4 && y > 1 && y < 4) ? sign : 'n'`  then there is your problem, it's not meant to be written that way.

Answer (score 4):

It gives you an error when compiling because the tenary operator must *return* a value. It's not a drop-in replacement for an if/else block.

The code does two vastly different things: one sets the value of an array, the other prints an error.

Answer (score 2):

try using something like this

```
board[x-1, y-1] = (x > 1 && x < 4 && y > 1 && y < 4) ? sign : '-';
```

The ternary execution will return a value

**However**, you should approach this differently, and fail before this even happens if the position is out of bounds - you really don't need a ternary here.

```
private int width = 3;
private int height = 3;

...

if ( x > width || y > height || x < 0 || y < 0 )
{
    // fail because position is out of the bounds of the board
}

board[x, y] = sign;
```

Comment: Awesome! See my edit for, what I think, is a more elegant solution. Cheers, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The result of the ternary operator is the result of the chosen expression, and this means both expressions need to have the same type.

If you were to use [the comma operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs06xbxh.aspx), for example, to ensure the second expression has the same type as the first, I think you'd find this compiles and runs just fine...

```
(x > 1 && x < 4 && y > 1 && y < 4) ? (board[x - 1, y - 1] = sign)
                                   : (Console.WriteLine("Error"), sign);
```

Mind you, it seems like an atrocious choice to me. We tend to use the ternary operator when we want to store the result of the choice. The `if/else` variant seems like the best choice here...

Comment: Thank you but writing 
    (x > 1 && x < 4 && y > 1 && y < 4) ? (board[x - 1, y - 1] = sign: (Console.WriteLine("Error"), sign);

doesn't work :(

Comment: Sorry Seb, but this still would not work as it throws a compilation error - a turnary **must** return a value, as simply `(x > 1 && x < 4 && y > 1 && y < 4)` is not a valid call.

Comment: @MattClark did you click the link regarding the comma operator from this answer and read?

Comment: @MattClark ternary doesn't *return* anything, and parens alone don't necessarily denote function calls. Your understanding of the language falls unfortunately short.

Comment: @PaoloVeneziani you're missing a ')'... Try copy/pasting my example so you get it right.